# iOS IDFA AppsFlyer - Events Won't Log

Tags: ios, objective-c, idfa, appsflyer, appsflyer-ios-sdk

In an app I am working on we are using `Appsflyer` to track events in the app.
We are using `Appsflyer` for years now, but since March 2020 we stopped seeing events in the console.

1. In Android App everything works fine
2. I've compared to commits from 2019, and there is no changes in the code related to logging the events
3. When I'm running the app through `xcode`, the events being logged, when I'm running the same build from `Test Flight`, the events not logged.
4. When we upload the App to `Appstore`, we don't check the `IDFA` checkbox, but we don't check it for other apps that using `Appsflyer`, and in other apps everything works fine, so I don't think it is relevant.

I will add more info to the post as we go.

Any ideas will be highly appreciated as I ran out of ideas. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

5. It seems that point "3" irrelevant, Because it seems that it worked only because I ran the app on `iOS 12`. That being said, it look like the event won't log only in `iOS >=13.0`
6. LAT Option is turned on in the iPhone settings

Comment: Hi Vadim, were you able to contact AppsFlyer support on this issue?

Comment: Had to leave the office right away, sending them an email right now.